# How to find shortest path assigning weights to intermediate nodes

Tags: graph-theory

I met a problem to find shortest path for assigning multiple salesmen (m) to n cities. But in my problem, each city has an attraction factor/weight that it can be visited more than once if attraction is high. It is likely a transformation of multiple travelling salesmen problem. I've searched a large number of literatures but found that most of algorithms are focusing on assigning weights to arcs. I am wondering who heard of or knew some algorithms fit my problem?

Thanks